Gas limits a foundry tests
I want to create a test for my NFT contract, that tests minting the "final" token for a contract with a large supply. To do this I want to send 10k mint() calls to my contract. This causes the test to fail with an OutOfGas error, which wouldn't happen in the real world because the calls would be broken up into multiple transactions.
Is it possible to accurately reflect gas usage in a forge test by "resetting" the gas used at specific points in the script? Or failing that, have an infinite limit for a particular test in forge? Or any other solution?
